# While loading data using Apache Pig to Hbase table, How to exclude columns where there is no data (just whitespace) in csv or text file for a row?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

Consider I have a table called customer_table with data as column family, Now I have a text file as follows:

`custno,firstname,lastname,age,profession`

( These are column names and not present in the text or csv file)

```
1,John,Wright,54,Coach  
2,Luke,,20,Student  
3,Mike,Jordan,26,    
4,William,Jones,21,Teacher
```

Here in the 2nd row and 3rd row there is no value for the column's lastname and profession respectively.

Now i want

```
STORE variable INTO 'hbase://customer_table' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage()
```

to exclude those columns(where there is no data or only whitespace) for that particular rows alone. Please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested [biconditionals](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html#arithmetic) in foreach ... generate statements. Another option would be to use UDF.

As a remark, either way, you will lose a schema so your fields will be nameless and values will be bytearrays in pig. I personally never tried writing such rows to hbase. Therefore no idea, how they will look like and how could you access them. I hope you have a good reason for doing something like this.